# Reading A Text File To Array List

Tags: java, android

I've been stuck on this problem for a few weeks now with no avail.
I am saving the contents of an array-list to a text file so that when the user opens the activity, the array list loads itself up for the user.

When i try to read the text file, and add the contents to the array-list, I get the following input inside the arraylist "Java.io.ObjectInputStream@b37391"

My array list will then look like this
[hello , leon, java.io.ObjectInputStream@b373791]

How can I read the text from the text file and display its contents on the array list

I have supplied the code used below, I have read many tutorials and stackoverflow questions but nothing seems to work. Some advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
  try {
     File f = new File(getFilesDir(), "anxfile.txt");
     FileInputStream readtheting = new FileInputStream(f);
     ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(readtheting);

     ois.readObject();

     arrayList.add(String.valueOf(ois));

     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     ois.close();

  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: You need to do `arrayList.add(String.valueOf(ois.readObject()))`.

Comment: If you have been stuck for weeks on that you didn't really consider looking for an answer or? Directly in the official documentation of ObjectInputStream it says how to work with it. There is even an example.

Comment: Link if you can't find it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html.
If you still have questions after reading this feel free to come back and ask again :)

Comment: Thanks for the link Ben, However I used this originally to get it working which is giving me above "Java.io.ObjectInputStream@b37391"

Comment: Dainu, thank you for your suggestion. Sadly this is giving me an java.io.EOFException

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

After importing these then:

```
public class ReadFile{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\tmotswagole\\My Documents\\Example.txt"));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
          for (int i =0; i<lines.size(); i++) {
            String[] items = lines.get(i).split("", 1);
            for (String s: items) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
           }

      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }   
   }

}
```

This is how you would execute that code fully

Comment: It gives me this... ����sr��java.util.ArrayListx����a���I��sizexp������w������t��helllx

Comment: @Leon I just made edits to fix up my original answer... this one works... I just tested it

Comment: Thanks for the help Thabiso, I used serialization to write to my text file so your method to read would not work. I have found a way to save the arraylist using shared preferences within the android OS.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use this for reading:

```
List<String> strings = Files.readAllLines(new File(getFilesDir(), "anxfile.txt").toPath());
```

and this one for writing:

```
Files.write(new File(getFilesDir(), "anxfile.txt").toPath(), <someArray>);
```